# Cordova + cordova-ios 6.1.0 - load local image

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, cordova-ios, cordovawebview

I have a cordova app that worked great prior to using cordova-ios 6.x.

This app downloads couple of images into cordova.file.dataDirectory for offline access.... so far I haven't been able to find a way to display this image other than using local webserver plugin.

Isn't there any other built-in way how to allow serve content from the cdvfile scheme ? [i need to set an img src] as there may be many images, converting to base64 is not an option for me.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone struggling as I was. There is a solution, which requires no significant change to the code.

There are 2 steps required:

First update your config.xml with following

```
<platform name="ios">    
  <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
  <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
 </platform>
```

Then convert your file:// link by using the undocumented method

```
window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(filePath)
```

This method performs the conversion into a virtual localhost link that makes the file accessible and bypasses the WkWebView restrictions. A little bit longer sample goes like this

```
let localFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'logo.png';
let convertedPath = window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(localFile);
document.getElementById("myImg").src = convertedPath;
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of cutting through the weeds!  That "window.WkWebView.convertFilePath" was extremely helpful.  I've been putting this WKWebView update off for a long time, exactly because I expected this to be a pain.  Your post was a huge help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After spending several days battling with it, the solution I found was to not use `cdvfile://` to serve the files on iOS. WkWebView really doesn't play nice with it.

However, WkWebView is perfectly fine loading assets from the native `file://` protocol, so you can convert the from `cdvfile://` to that using this:

```
const resolveIosPath = (path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, entry => {
    resolve(window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(entry.toURL())
  },
  reject
)
```

To use it, simply run your path through that method and apply the result to the `src` attribute:

```
// With async/await
const img = document.createElement("img")
img.src = await resolveIosPath("cdvfile://images/logo.png")
document.body.appendChild(img)

// With Promise chain
resolveIosPath("cdvfile://images/logo.png").then((src) => {
  const img = document.createElement("img")
  img.src = src
  document.body.appendChild(img)
})

// With synchronous img mount, but src added asynchronously
const img = document.createElement("img")
document.body.appendChild(img)
resolveIosPath("cdvfile://images/logo.png").then((src) => {
  img.src = src
})
```

If you don't like having to do all of that asynchronously, you can save the root sometime during your app's initialization:

```
// Storing on `window` just as an example, the point is to make it globally available
window.cacheRoot = await resolveIosPath("cdvfile://")
```

...and then you can use it synchronously like this:

```
const img = document.createElement("img")
img.src = window.cacheRoot + "logo.png"
document.body.appendChild(img)
```