# Cordova iOS 6.1.0 How to display images on external screen in WKwebview

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I have a Cordova app that uses this plugin ([cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen](https://github.com/josiaho/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen)) to display images/media full screen on an external screen via Airplay/HDMI adapter (similar to Apple’s Keynote).

All worked smoothly with UIwebview, but I’m having trouble displaying media on my external screen with WKwebview. I’m now using Cordova iOS 6.1.1 (CLI 10.0).

I’m using [window.WkWebView.convertFilePath()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63818380/379675) to display media on my primary (control) screen, but neither the converted file url nor the “file://...” url (`cordova.file.dataDirectory + ‘image.jpg’`) work in the external screen.

**Additional info:**

- My external screen is launched via `ExternalScreen.loadHTML('secondary.html');` , but Cordova does not appear to be available in the window of the external screen (even when cordova.js is included in secondary.html).
- My “whitelist” meta data is the same in both my index.html (control) and secondary.html (display) documents.

How do I get image URL’s that’ll display on my second (external) screen?

**UPDATE:**
I've updated the getWebView function of the [plugin](https://github.com/josiaho/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen) adding `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs`, `allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs`, `allowsInlineMediaPlayback`, and `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` configurations:

```
- (WKWebView*)getWebView {
    if (!self.externalWebView) {
        UIScreen* externalScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex: 1];
        CGRect screenBounds = externalScreen.bounds;
        self.externalWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds configuration: [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]];

        // I added these four configurations...
        [self.externalWebView.configuration.preferences setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
        [self.externalWebView.configuration setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"];
        self.externalWebView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = TRUE;
        self.externalWebView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone;

        self.externalWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
        self.externalWindow.screen = externalScreen;
        self.externalWindow.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.externalWindow addSubview:self.externalWebView];
        [self.externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        self.externalWindow.hidden = NO;
    }
    return self.externalWebView;
}
```

Unfortunately, these changes do *not* seem to impact the `externalView`. I'm temporarily using this plugin as a workaround ([cordova-plugin-wkwebview-sandbox-webserver](https://github.com/bigeyex/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-sandbox-webserver)), but even with that I can't get HTML5 videos to autoplay - so I'm questioning whether I'm even putting the configuration settings in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this plugin has not been updated. From what I can see in the plugin, it is trying to load using file:// which is not working anymore out of the box.

```
    NSString* a = @"file://";
    baseURLAddress = [a stringByAppendingString:baseURLAddress];
```

You could try to add the preferences `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs` and `allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` to the WKWebView that is created by this plugin in the `getWebView` method in [this file](https://github.com/josiaho/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen/blob/master/src/ios/WKWebViewExternalScreen.m)

You can base your work on [this plugin](https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr/blob/master/src/ios/CDVWKWebViewFileXhr.m), code for reference

```
 [wkWebView.configuration.preferences setValue:@(_allowFileAccessFromFileURLs) forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

While this is not a straight answer, cloning cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen and adding theses preferences is your best shot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, adding `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs` and `allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` to the the getWebView configuration didn't solve the issue. Temporarily I'm using this plugin (https://github.com/bigeyex/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-sandbox-webserver) to serve the files, but videos will not autoplay either (even with `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` and `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` configuration settings) - so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right either - I'll update my question with example code.

Comment: Can you try to serve a file that is in your www folder to start with a "clean" base with your problem ? Also are you using this plugin I suggested for your main webview ?

Comment: Yes, the recommended plugin (https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr) works on the primary webview, but not the externalScreen for some reason?

Comment: Since the sandbox server plugin is accomplishing my end goal - I’ll mark this question as answered and focus on my next challenge (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115592/cordova-ios-6-autoplay-video-in-external-screen). I was hoping that there would be a way to set the WKwebview configuration for the External web view that might solve both issues. Thanks for your input!