# Cordova iOS 6+ Autoplay Video in External Screen

Tags: ios, cordova, html5-video, wkwebview

I'm using [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen](https://github.com/josiaho/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen) to playback inline media on a secondary screen (via AirPlay or HDMI adapter). The media loads fine but does not autoplay videos in the external webview. (autoplay works fine in primary webview)

In my config.xml I have the following:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" /> 
<preference name="MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback" value="none" />
```

I have attempted adding the following configuration in [WKWebViewExternalScreen.m](https://github.com/josiaho/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-external-screen/blob/master/src/ios/WKWebViewExternalScreen.m) (lines 20-21):

```
- (WKWebView*)getWebView {
    if (!self.externalWebView) {
        UIScreen* externalScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex: 1];
        CGRect screenBounds = externalScreen.bounds;

        self.externalWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds configuration: [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]];

        // I ADDED THESE TWO LINES
        self.externalWebView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;// Updated 'true' to 'YES'
        self.externalWebView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone;

        self.externalWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];

        self.externalWindow.screen = externalScreen;
        self.externalWindow.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.externalWindow addSubview:self.externalWebView];
        [self.externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        self.externalWindow.hidden = NO;
    }
    return self.externalWebView;
}
```

I've tried programmatically triggering an HTML5 `video.play()` after the second view is loaded. No dice.

How can I autoplay HTML5 videos in this second view? (I'm using Cordova CLI 10.0.0 & Cordova iOS 6.1.1)

**UPDATE:**
I've created a sample Cordova iOS Xcode project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/874m6jlxum8s14v/Looper.zip?dl=0). In Simulator, Menu > I/O > External Displays > 1280 x 720 (720p) will open `secondary.html` the secondary WebView. BOTH `index.html` and `secondary.html` contain the VIDEO tag: `<video src="img/fireandiceocean.mp4" preload autoplay playsinline loop />`. In the primary view, the video plays in a loop automatically as expected, but in the Extended Display, the video does not autoplay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova iOS 6.1.0 How to display images on external screen in WKwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032653/cordova-ios-6-1-0-how-to-display-images-on-external-screen-in-wkwebview)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That question is about file read access/permission within a secondary webview. This question is about allowing HTML5 video to Autoplay within a secondary webview. There may be a WKWebViewConfiguration answer to both questions that I can't figure out? Maybe I should be asking how to set WKWebViewConfiguration for a secondary webview? With UIwebView - the config.xml preferences applied to all app web views. With WKwebview, the preferences only appear to affect the main/primary webview.

Comment: self.externalWebView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = TRUE should be YES

Comment: Good catch! Although it didn't seem to make a difference in the desired outcome.

Comment: I've added an example Xcode project :)