# Cannot display image from local in Cordova / iOS

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, local-files

My Cordova app has to display image from local file. It worked fine until I had to move on to Cordova 10 and WKWebView.

I know have the following message :

> Get
> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/93F87A6C-0069-4190-ACA5-C5EF7F5D1C8F/Library/NoCloud/story__le-petit-chaperon/page-93fd607b-3f9b-42bf-89d4-09def7874b72.jpg
> The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted

I have installed plugin with no success https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix

I also tried some scheme solution described here [Cordova + cordova-ios 6.1.0 - load local image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814652/cordova-cordova-ios-6-1-0-load-local-image) but it screws all the path : angular templates cannot be loaded, navigation issues...

I am lost and frustrated for something that worked perfectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try [cordova-plugin-ios-xhr](https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr) instead then set your preferences like

```
 <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks Eric but it does not work : Still having the message :  
    GET file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C66D64F-F077-4AB3-89C4-486334D9AF0A/Library/NoCloud/story__feerie-du-printemps//969D8471-2DB8-442E-AC1C-6DEDEF4470F8.jpg The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted. 

Did you actually do it and make it work ?

Thanks again.

Comment: When you use this plugin, then you can access images relative to /www (document root in cordova) but I realize your images might not be in a folder in /www

Comment: No there are not because they can may be generated by users action (camera or else)

Comment: Your path is not the proper path for cordova. Where are you getting this path from ? A plugin ?

Comment: @Eric, I'm getting exactly the same start of the file:// URL as Tom is, from using cordova.file.dataDirectory , with the latest cordova-plugin-file .  Do you know what the proper path should be?  Would this be a bug in cordova-plugin-file?  I'm using Cordova 11, and trying to run on an actual iPhone SE.  My images are not loading on the iPhone; the simulator works fine.