# Cordova and iOS : Configuring scheme and hostname to display local images in <img src=...>

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, url-scheme, cordova-ios

My Cordova app has to display image from local file. It worked fine until I had to move on to Cordova 10 and WKWebView.

I am struggling with the solution given here :
[Cordova + cordova-ios 6.1.0 - load local image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814652/cordova-cordova-ios-6-1-0-load-local-image/6783488)
where I need to configure a scheme in my config.xml :

```
<preference name="scheme" value="storyplayr-app" />

<preference name="hostname"> value="storyplayr-localhost" />
```

But when I do that, all my navigation is superseeded by this and I have the following errors :

> ERROR Internal navigation rejected - not set for
> url='unsafe:storyplayr-app://storyplayr-host/index.html%23/bibliotheque/allemand-deutsche'
> 2021-06-04 11:19:30.424473+0200 Storyplayr pre[2920:603324] ERROR
> External navigation rejected - not set for
> url='unsafe:storyplayr-app://storyplayr-host/index.html%23/bibliotheque/allemand-deutsche'

How can I have this "config" apply only to src="file:///..." and not to the rest ?

Maybe this not not make sense but I am lost...

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: I had the same problem and resolved it. The unsafe: prefix comes from Angular. You need to whitelist yourscheme: in the Angular config.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova provide a method to convert `file://` uri to `yourscheme://` uri in wkwebview

```
window.WkWebView.convertFilePath('file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{UUID}/tmp/cache/avatar/1.jpg')
```

got

```
yourscheme://yourhostname/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{UUID}/tmp/cache/avatar/1.jpg
```